# Как установить Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0?

Tags: c#, .net, office, ms-access, office-interop

На ПК стоит 2013 Office x32 и почему-то не могу использовать драйвер `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` в своем проекте.

Просто, получаю какую-то абстрактную ошибку:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException: 'Внешний компонент создал исключение.'

Я обнаружил, следующую закономерность:

Если поставить руками Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable, то все работает, НО до того момента, как руками будет запущена какая-то офисная программа.

После этого офис выполняет какую-то конфигурацию
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
 и после этого, начинает вылетать исключение.

Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема? Неужели 2013 офис не может работать с Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0? Jet 4.0 прекрасно работает, но там нету некоторых функций, которые можно использовать в запросах к Access. например Replace.

В чем косяк?